# What are the most common deep reinforcement learning algorithms and models apart from DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, deep-rl

Recently, I have completed Atari Breakout (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5602.pdf) with DQN.

Similar to DQN, what are the most common deep reinforcement learning algorithms and models in 2020? It seems that DQN is outdated and policy gradients are preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several common deep reinforcement algorithms and models apart from [deep Q networks (or deep Q learning)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evmnih/docs/dqn.pdf). I will list some of them below (along with a link to the paper that introduced them), but note that some of these may not be state-of-the-art (at least, not anymore, and it's likely that all of these will be replaced in the future).

- [Double DQN (DDQN)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.06461.pdf) (2015)
- [Duelling DQN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06581.pdf) (2015)
- [Trust Region Policy Optimization (TRPO)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/schulman15.pdf) (2015)
- [Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient (DDPG)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf) (2016)
- [Asynchronous Advantage Actor-Critic (A3C)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/mniha16.pdf) (2016)
- [Hindsight Experience Replay (HER)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/453fadbd8a1a3af50a9df4df899537b5-Paper.pdf) (2017)
- [Proximal policy optimization (PPO)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf) (2017)
- [Twin Delayed Deep Deterministic policy gradient algorithm (TD3)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/fujimoto18a/fujimoto18a.pdf) (2018)
- [Soft Actor-Critic (SAC)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/haarnoja18b/haarnoja18b.pdf) (2018)

For an exhaustive overview of deep RL algorithms and models, maybe take a look at this pre-print [Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.06339.pdf) (2018) by Yuxi Li.